# start using pre-compiled mysql, but get: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets

I knew the question I am asking is somewhat alike with other guys, but my case is a little different:
I did not install mysql-server using yum, nor did I install it with rpm or compile-makeinstall.
I simply downloaded the compressed precompiled binary from the official website:
http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.1/mysql-5.1.73-linux-x86_64-glibc23.tar.gz

**So, there is no /etc/init.d/mysqld, the "service mysqld start/stop/restart" could not work.**

I unarchived it and initialized the DB with：

```
./scripts/mysql_install_db
```

then start it with：

```
./bin/mysqld_safe &
```

everything work fine till now, but when I tried to connect it using mysql, it prompted:

```
# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

The data directory was changed to:

```
drw-rw-rw-  4 mysql   mysql   4096 Jan  3 14:03 mysql
```

The following stop command also could not work:

```
# mysqladmin shutdown
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

The mysqld_safe process and mysqld process are all working fine:

```
# ps -ef | grep mysqld
root     10977  5685  0 14:03 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./bin/mysqld_safe
mysql    11154 10977  0 14:03 pts/2    00:00:00 /root/mysql-5.1.73-linux-x86_64-glibc23/bin/mysqld 
--basedir=/root/mysql-5.1.73-linux-x86_64-glibc23 
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql 
--log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log 
--pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
--socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
root     11650  5685  0 14:26 pts/2    00:00:00 grep mysqld
```

some config information in the /etc/my.cnf is :

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
old_passwords=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# ps -ef | grep mysqld
root     10977  5685  0 14:03 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./bin/mysqld_safe
mysql    11154 10977  0 14:03 pts/2    00:00:00 /root/mysql-5.1.73-linux-x86_64-glibc23/bin/mysqld 
--basedir=/root/mysql-5.1.73-linux-x86_64-glibc23 
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql 
--log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log 
--pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
--socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

your socket is at `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`
guess you are using `/usr/bin/mysql`

to connect to mysql, you can update `/etc/my.cnf`, set `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` for `[mysql]` section

```
[mysql]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

To fix `mysqladmin` you need to add the section `[mysqladmin]` also

```
[mysqladmin]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Alternatively you can add `[client]`, it should work for both `mysql` and `mysqladmin`

```
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: I did set the option: socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Since your mysqld is running with `--socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`, you need to set the same for mysql client, in `/etc/my.cnf` you should set for `[mysql]`, I updated the post, hope it's clearer

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much! But I found if I use yum install mysql-server, I could start run the mysql successfully, without the config [mysql] option. What I only have in the /etc/my.cnf is [mysqld] option. Could you tell me why?

Comment: I don't have yum installed mysql-server, if you install both `mysql-server` and `mysql` from YUM, guess they are expecting socket to be at the same location. or YUM updated `my.cnf` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to do a 
    mysql.server start

Comment: I didn't install the mysql-server using yum rpm or make install.